# Always execute post statement in a jenkins pipeline when a conditional statement is met

Tags: jenkins, amazon-web-services, jenkins-pipeline, aws-cloudformation

Although it seems counterintuitive, I would like to execute an always statement when a conditional is met. In my pipeline, my post statement should always destroy my AWS CloudFormation Stack if a variable is set to true. Below is the post statement which is not correct.

```
post{
    always {
        when {
            expression { DeleteStack == 'true'}
        }
        stage("Delete All Stacks") {               
            steps {
                script {
                    withAWS(region:'us-west-2', credentials:'jenkins-deploy') {
                        def outputs = cfnDelete(
                            stack:"${CFTBatchStackName}", 
                            pollInterval:1000)
                    }
                    withAWS(region:'us-west-2', credentials:'jenkins-deploy') {
                        def outputs = cfnDelete(
                            stack:"${CFTVPCStackName}", 
                            pollInterval:1000)
                    }
                    withAWS(region:'us-west-2', credentials:'jenkins-deploy') {
                    def outputs = cfnDelete(
                        stack:"${CFTSelfDeleteName}", 
                        pollInterval:1000)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can I achieve this using a declarative pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when), the `when` directive is only allowed inside a `stage`. You have to use the `script` directive if you want to use conditional statements:

```java
post {
  always {
    script {
      if (DeleteStack == 'true') {
        // Destroy what you want !
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to do what you want with Declarative, but it certainly is possible with Scripted:

```
try {
  // your Pipeline code here
} finally {
  if (!DeleteStack) { return }

  [
    CFTBatchStackName,
    CFTVPCStackName,
    CFTSelfDeleteName,
  ].each { stack->
    withAWS(region:'us-west-2', credentials:'jenkins-deploy') {
      def outputs = cfnDelete(
        stack: stack,
        pollInterval: 1000,
      )
    }
  }
}
```